# Zend 2 View Helper - Using Abstract Helper to render another helper content

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I have implemented a Zend View Helper called contentByKey which renders some HTML in my CMS engine. I would like to implement it so that this View Helper is the only helper called within my markup (passed a key to find content in DB). When it attempts to build the HTML content, it needs to be able to dispatch another View Helpers render within the View Helper Class. My class implements AbstractHelper. See below:

```
class ContentByKey extends AbstractHelper{

public function __invoke($key){
    /* 1. Fetch content from DB and check type */

    /* 2. Content type = "foo";*/

    /* 3. NEEDED LOGIC - Invoke fooHelper here (needs to process additional logic before rendering so simply rendering a different script isnt enough) */
}
```

Should this not be the best method to implement what I need, I'd gladly accept any other suggestions.

Comment: do you want to call another view helper in `__invoke` ?

Comment: Yes, and render that view helpers content not ContentByKey's

Comment: Inject the ViewHelpers you need into your own ViewHelper

Comment: Can you provide an example @Sam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A view helper is constructed by the view helper plugin manager (or, `Zend\View\HelperPluginManager`). This manager injects the view renderer object in every view helper (see `getView()`/`setView()` on [GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/AbstractHelper.php#L23-L43)). It enables you to call other helpers:

```
<?php
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class ContentByKey extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($key)
    {
        // fetch data from database
        // $text = ...

        // example: translate this text via the translator

        $translated = $this->getView()->translate($text);
        return $translated;
    }
}
```

It's quite a common way to do these things, so it's OK to do this. Alternatively, you could inject the view helper in your own helper. The example gets a bit skewed, as you would inject a Translator object instead of the translate view helper, but anyhow:

```
<?php
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate as TranslateHelper;

class ContentByKey extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $translate;

    public function __construct(TranslateHelper $translate)
    {
        $this->translate = $translate;
    }

    public function __invoke($key)
    {
        // fetch data from database
        // $text = ...

        // example: translate this text via the translator

        $translated = $this->translate($text);
        return $translated;
    }
}
```

You have to inject the helper this way, so you need to create a factory for your helper:

```
<?php
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

use MyModule\View\Helper\ContentByKey;

class ContentByKeyFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $viewManager = $serviceLocator->get('ViewHelperManager');
        $translate   = $viewManager->get('translate');

        $helper = new ContentByKey($translate);
        return $helper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jurian, this is perfect :)

Comment: Jurian, I've realized that I need to execute the helper dynamically (not knowing beforehand which helper will be returned). Could you provide a way to do this? In your example you use Translator as the fixed helper, but my helper differs depending on what is pulled from the DB (type field has the name of the helper).

Comment: I see there is a plugin broker - $view->plugin('helperName') that can be used as long as your helper implements the __invoke method. Maybe you have a better solution?

Comment: @Blyde `__invoke($helpername, $morevars...)` and then inside `$this->$helpername($text)` should work if I'm not mistaken right now

Comment: @Sam Thank you, I played around and ended up with the above too :)

Comment: @Blyde: you can use method #1 and call `$this->getView()->helper1()` and `$this->getView()->helper2()`. An alternative is to use method #2 (injecting dependencies) but then you don't inject the view *helper* but the view *plugin manager*. Then you got the manager and in your code you call `$helper1 = $this->manager->get('helper1')` etc.

Comment: Got it working, thanks Jurian. Your solutions above were a great help